# What are quantifiers that require a PDA?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Can someone give me examples of quantifiers that can't be solved with FSA (like all, any, at least x, etc.), i.e
 can't be defined in first-order logic, but require a PDA to determine? I know "most" is one, but I couldn't come up with any other examples.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards.

Comment: What [FSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSA) ?

Comment: What [PDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDA_(disambiguation)) ?

Comment: FSA = Finite State Automaton, PDA = PushDown Automaton (FSA extended with working memory, e.g. a stack)

Comment: @user2999349 you might want to move your question to https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "more than [some set], "half of" are some more examples. Basically, everything that requires counting relative to the size of a set rather than absolute numbers, since in this case both the number of matching elements encountered and the number of elements of the set in total need to be tracked. This can only be achieved with a stack, hence, a PDA.

Comment: The comparison of numbers (as in "more than") that requires a stack resembles the problem of $a^n b^n$. This might make it easier for you to imagine why these quantifiers can not be solved by a FSA.